# Best Translation from Greek to English

Tags: translation-philosophy

Can you direct me to the best English translation from the best Greek manuscripts showing accurately the moods and tenses in the translation?
Thank you

Comment: Maybe re-tag your question.  Re: Close votes. "Questions tagged [tools-of-biblical-studies]  Ask Question For requests for resources that help analyze the Biblical text in a specific way, or questions about how to use those resources."

Comment: It's not clear if you're interested in something like an interlinear, or are just after opinions about favourite translations. Either way, it's not really on-topic for this site.

Comment: Biblehub.com is a good place for a start. There you will find interlinear  and many language tools, parallel Bible versions, Aramaic in English, commentaries, and much more. Try it see for your self. Its free!!! I personally use it with other paid Bible apps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a hardcopy book, I use:

*The English-Greek Revrse Interlinear New Testament*

[https://www.amazon.com/English-Greek-Reverse-Interlinear-New-Testament/dp/158134628X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/158134628X)

There is a "Look Inside" feature on the Amazon link and you can see if it can be adapted for word-for-word use by filling in Eng. for Greek words that are 'skipped over' from the ESV translation.

---

Wish there was such an interlinear for the Hebrew, for sure. I use both the ISA2 Program from scripture4all.org (still available under the ISA3 beta download area). ISA2 allows study with and without nikkud.

and Scholars Gateway for the grammar https://scholarsgateway.com/search/WLC-LXX-YLT/Genesis/1:1-5.

Neither are perfect, but *I'm* definitely grateful for both resources.

Answer (score 0):

That is not an easy question to answer for a number of reasons. You must first understand that there is no such thing as a word-for-word translation simply because there are words in Hebrew and Greek that have no English equivalents. Sometimes, the only option is to convey the sense of the original word and this can sometimes be subjective. Another problem arises in determining the best textual evidences among the ancient manuscripts. Some are more reliable than other. I would say that there are some English translations that stand out above the rest such as the RSV and the ASV. Other good translations are the NASV and the ESV. All translations have their shortcomings and some are stronger in particular areas than others.

Comment: Use an interlinear such as https://biblehub.com/interlinear/1_peter/2-9.htm  My suggestion is BLB for a reliable literal translation here >> https://biblehub.com/1_peter/2-9.htm

Comment: That is a good tool and I use it a great deal. I have a background in Greek but know absolutely nothing about the Hebrew so, I have to depend solely on the scholarship of others in that area.

Answer (score 0):

After spending some effort to find a literal Bible translation, I found the following Bible which attempted to provide a word-to-word literal translation of both the Old Testament (Hebrew) and New Testament. Hope this could be a good resource for you as well.

The Interlinear Bible, Hebrew-Greek-English, with Strong’s Concordance Numbers above Each Word, 2nd Edition (c) 1986 by Jay P. Green, Sr.

God bless you!

Comment: J. P. Green's Interlinear does not provide translit nor parts of speech. And it's one thing to 'stretch' a translation over the Greek - quite another to try to do it with the Hebrew, IMO. Here's a link that shows the text:  https://www.christianbook.com/interlinear-hebrew-english-bible-volume-edition/9781565639775/pd/639774